# Upgrading Moto G to KitKat broke USB OTG

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb-on-the-go

After upgrading the Moto G to KitKat, USB OTG no longer works. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

[Nexus Media Importer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer) can restore USB OTG support. [Source](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/b0d3e54f57).